# Absolute condition number

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, condition-number

I am solving the absolute condition for a problem $f(\vec{x})$.
The definition is clear, $K_{abs}$ is the minimal number greater zero such that
$|| f(\vec{x}) - f(\tilde{\vec{x}})  || \leq K_{abs} || \vec{x} -\tilde{\vec{x}}||$

Now I also found that I can just compute it as
$K_{abs} = || f'(\vec{x}) ||$

How does it follow from the definition?
Specifically, is it valid for any differentiable $f$ (also nonlinear)?

Comment: That's not quite true. For example, $e^x-1$ is definitely not bounded by $|x|$. I think what you're essentially looking for comes from the mean value theorem: $f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(y)(x-x_0)$ where $y$ is between $x$ and $x_0$. If $x$ is close enough to $x_0$ then you can approximate $f'(y)$ by $f'(x_0)$ (so that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \leq (|f'(x_0)+\epsilon) |x-x_0|$ for $x$ near $x_0$). But what "close enough" means depends on $f$. Taylor's theorem is also related here.

Comment: I don't really get the example... the derivative of $e^x -1$ is $e^x$, so if I would use $K_{abs} = || f'(x) || = || e^x ||$, this should be unbounded?

Comment: Could you maybe explain how I use the Taylor argument for multidimensional functions?
So far as I understood, for one-dimensional the proof goes like:
$f(x) - f(x_0) = \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} \cdot (x -x_0)$ (simple multiplication of the LHS by $(x -x_0)$).
And by Taylor we get for "close enough" $x$ and $x_0$ and differentiable $f$, that
$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} \approx f'(x)$.  
I need it for a two-dimensional $f$ but I'm not sure how to extend it for that case.

Comment: The $K$ is supposed to be constant. But there is no universal constant that lets you control $e^x-1$ in terms of $|x|$. On the other hand there is if you restrict attention to a bounded domain.

Comment: As for the multidimensional case, there is a multidimensional Taylor's theorem. For real-valued functions of a vector variable, the first order term involves the gradient and the second order term involves the Hessian. There are higher order terms but they don't get used much because they start involving higher rank tensors.

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured it out now. Aside from that, $K$ is in fact $K(x)$. I wrote the definition a bit too sloppy. It does not need to be a universal contstant for the whole domain of the function. A function can have a good condition on some interval and bad condition on another...

Comment: You still can't expect $|f (x)-f (y)| \leq K (x)|x-y|$ without confining $y $ to a bounded region. Again think about $e^x $. But you can patch together the domain of the function into a bunch of bounded domains with different Lipschitz constants, provided it is locally Lipschitz (which it is if it is continuously differentiable).